# Receive data from a child tab page opened by the parent tab - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was opening a link (called new_url) from my website by using an `iframe`,

The `new_url` page had a button on it. When I clicked that button, I use `parent.postMessage("some message", "*");` to submit some data to my parent page and I received that using

```
  window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {


  }, false);
```

However, now, I'm not using `iframe` and using `parent.window.open("new_url",'_newtab');` instead.

My question is that can I received the data from the child tab in the parent tab the same way I received it in case of the `iframe`. If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

Use `window.opener.postMessage("some data", "*");` in your child tab.

`window.opener` is the solution.

Comment: Be careful using "*" with postMessage in production code. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage): 
_"Always provide a specific targetOrigin, not *, if you know where the other window's document should be located. Failing to provide a specific target discloses the data you send to any interested malicious site."_